# set $rootScope variable after phonegap deviceready event is fired

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Is there any way to set $rootScope variable in my angular app after the deviceready event is trigger?

```
var application = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
onDeviceReady: function() {
    //set angular app $rootScope variable
}
```

};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a property in the **$rootScope** in your **deviceready** event handler, make sure to wrap it in an $apply method call, since the **deviceready** event occurs outside of AngularJS.  Here is an example:

```
angular.module('myapp').run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $rootScope.myVariable = "variable value";
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: where do you have to write this?
I have my onDeviceReady event in the index.js file, and I create my angular app module in main.js. Should I copy this after that?